# How do I enable users to create repos, but not give them access to add members to the team?

Tags: git, admin, restrict

Is there a permission in Github that would allow team members to create new repos, but not enable them to add new members to the team?   I'd like for our team to be able to create, update and share repos, but I'd rather they couldn't just add anyone to the team.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think this is not available in github. You can check this [Git Different Access Levels](https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions) for a clear understanding of permissions depending on user/organisation accounts.

If you give access to create repos, addition and removal of collaborators is present in that.